# jekyll builds although .nojekyll is present

Tags: yaml, jekyll, workflow, github-pages

I am converting .md to .html and want to host these files on gh-pages. The problem is that jekyll-build-pages@v1 is being executed despite the presence of .nojekyll file and it throws an error since I don't want to use it and my project is not intended for jekyll. Why?

ERROR:

```
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
with:
source: ./docs
destination: ./docs/_site
future: false
build_revision: f4c9e5c0cb46a994aeb7066e4f4f11c4596de8ff
verbose: true
token: ***
...
Configuration file: none
  Logging at level: debug
      GitHub Pages: github-pages v228
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.3
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 
'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

docs.yaml (gh-pages action):

```
name: Build and Deploy Docs
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    concurrency: ci-${{ github.ref }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install pandoc
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pandoc

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x

      - name: Install styling
        run: npm install github-markdown-css

      - name: Build 
        run: |
          #!/bin/bash

          mkdir dist
          touch dist/.nojekyll
          mv node_modules/github-markdown-css/github-markdown.css docs/github-markdown.css
          cp docs/*.css dist/
          if [ -d "docs/img/" ]; then
            cp -r docs/img/ dist/img/
          fi

          for file in docs/*.md; do
            name=$(basename "$file" .md)
            pandoc "$file" -f markdown -t html -o "dist/$name.html"
          done

          for file in dist/*.html; do
            name=$(basename "$file" .html)
            content=$(cat "$file")

            echo -e "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang=\"en\">
              <head>
                <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
                <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">
                <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">
                <title>Docs</title>
                $(for cssfile in dist/*.css; do
                    cssname=$(basename "$cssfile")
                    if [[ "$cssname" != "github-markdown.css" && "$cssname" != "style.css" ]]; then
                      echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./$cssname\">"
                    fi
                  done)
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./github-markdown.css\">
                <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./style.css\">
              </head>

              <body class=\"markdown-body\">
              ${content}
              </body>
            </html>" > "dist/$name.html"
          done

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          folder: dist
          branch: docs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/-username-/-project-/settings/pages > Build and deployment

Source: "Deploy from branch"
Branch: "branch": docs and "folder": docs was selected (changed it to (root)),
but no docs folder exists in the docs branch (the error message makes sense now...). Thank you GitHub for letting me choose a folder that doesn't exist :/. I feel really dumb rn.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `.nojekyll` file is in the root directory. Additionally, you may need to [manually commit the file](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/issues/354#issuecomment-653876280) to your `gh-pages` branch. Finally, consider altering your build process such that it generates the `.nojekyll` itself prior to the GitHub pages push if possible. I personally find this to be a cleaner solution as the build process doesn't change based on some magic file that someone may not know about; everything affecting it is one place.